# Mutable reference to a tuple as input parameter

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I seem to have fallen into the hole known as "fighting the borrow checker" on this one. I have the following function:

```
fn draw_pair(decks: &(&mut Deck, &mut Deck)) -> (Card, Card) {
    let (&mut p1, &mut p2) = decks;

    (p1.draw_card(), p2.draw_card())
}
```

I get the following error:

```
expected type: &(&mut Deck, &mut Deck)
found type: (_, _)
```

The idea is to take mutable references the contents of the tuple. I see no reason to mutate the tuple itself. This function will be running in a loop.

I've tried writing `let &(&mut p1, &mut p2) = decks;` instead, but it tells me it can't move out of borrowed contents.

Here's the function that calls `draw_pair`:

```
fn play(decks: (Deck, Deck)) {
    loop {
        let cards = draw_pair(&decks);
        // actual game not yet implemented
    }
}
```

This too gives me an error, saying it expects `&(&mut Deck, &mut Deck)` but is getting `&(Deck, Deck)`.

Comment: You're passing an &(Deck, Deck) to your draw_pair function, not the expected &(&mut Deck, &mut Deck).

Comment: @SplittyDev I'm aware of that.

Comment: @SplittyDev the data I have at hand is immutable by default

Comment: I just updated my answer to include a better version of the code without the ugly clones and tuple references.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you want to obtain references using pattern matching and destructuring, use [`ref` instead of `&`](http://rustbyexample.com/scope/borrow/ref.html).  Use `let (ref mut p1, ref mut p2)` instead, and dereference `deck`.

You have to note that you cannot mutate immutable data. You can either use your own mutable clones, or work without mutation. Making `decks` in `play` mutable is the only way to obtain mutable references to the inner data in `draw_pair`. The following code solves your problem:

```
fn draw_pair(decks: &mut (Deck, Deck)) -> (Card, Card) {
    let (ref mut p1, ref mut p2) = *decks;

    (p1.draw_card(), p2.draw_card())
}

fn play(mut decks: (Deck, Deck)) {
    loop {
        let cards = draw_pair(&mut decks);
        // actual game not yet implemented
    }
}
```

If the `decks` pair you receive in `play` is immutable, there's no other way around it but to maintain your own cloned and mutable `Deck`s like @wimh does in his answer. If you want to create your own mutable clone more concisely, the following one liner will help: `&(&mut decks.0.clone(), &mut decks.1.clone())`

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't move out of the borrowed mutable references, you'll have to clone the fields.

```
fn main() {
    play((&mut Deck(0), &mut Deck(0)));
}

#[derive(Clone)]
struct Deck(i32);

fn play(decks: (&mut Deck, &mut Deck)) {
    let cards = draw_pair(&decks);
}

fn draw_pair(decks: &(&mut Deck, &mut Deck)) -> (i32, i32) {
    let mut p1 = decks.0.clone();
    let mut p2 = decks.1.clone();
    (0, 0)
}
```

Here's a [Playpen](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=d2690093bfaaa0c02a26c17bab3b3311&version=stable&backtrace=0) and [here's a version](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=663ca03dd42c6cb08293792d050c798a&version=stable&backtrace=0) that preserves the `play` signature.

Honestly though, I think in this case, adding a new type to represent the tuple would be a more clean and readable solution.

Ideally, I'd do it like that:

```
struct Deck {}
struct Card {}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Pair<T> {
    first: T,
    second: T,
}

impl<T> Pair<T> {
    pub fn new(first: T, second: T) -> Pair<T> {
        Pair { first: first, second: second }
    }
}

fn play(decks: Pair<Deck>) {
    let mut decks = decks;
    let cards = draw_pair(&mut decks);
}

fn draw_pair(decks: &mut Pair<Deck>) -> Pair<Card> {
    Pair::new(Card {}, Card {})
}
```

Comment: That's not an ideal solution though. The line which makes it all work `let mut decks = decks` is a bad hack, which should be avoided at all costs. It doesn't make a difference in such a small application, but it will in a multithreaded/concurrent scenario. Something which is immutable should not be mutated at any cost.

Comment: How is this something that should be avoided at all costs? You own the Pair<T>, so you can obtain a mutable reference to it. This will never cause any problems. In a multi-threaded scenario you'd be synchronizing it anyway, using a Cell<T> or Mutex<T>. Alternatively, you can change the Pair<Deck> to a &mut Pair<Deck> and you'll be good.

Answer (score 0):

This is the first error:

```
8 |     let (&mut p1, &mut p2) = decks;
  |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected reference, found tuple
  |
  = note: expected type `&(&mut Deck, &mut Deck)`
  = note:    found type `(_, _)`
```

The easiest way to fix that is dereferencing the right size (`*decks`), but then you get the other error:

```
8 |     let (&mut p1, &mut p2) = *decks;
  |          ^^^^^--
  |          |    |
  |          |    hint: to prevent move, use `ref p1` or `ref mut p1`
  |          cannot move out of borrowed content
```

As hinted using `ref` fixes this:

```
let (&mut ref p1, &mut ref p2) = *decks;
```

But there is no need to fully destructure the left side, you can also use

```
let (ref p1, ref p2) = *decks;
```

Here is a [minimum implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to reproduce your problem, with the fix applied:

```
struct Card{}
struct Deck{}
impl Deck {
    fn draw_card(&self) -> Card { Card {}}
}

fn draw_pair(decks: &(&mut Deck, &mut Deck)) -> (Card, Card) {
    let (ref p1, ref p2) = *decks;

    (p1.draw_card(), p2.draw_card())
}

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

edit: here is a solution for your `play` function without modifying it's signature:

```
struct Card{}

#[derive(Clone)]
struct Deck{}
impl Deck {
    fn draw_card(&self) -> Card { Card {}}
}

fn play(decks: (Deck, Deck)) {
    loop {
        let (ref deck1, ref deck2) = decks;
        let mut deck1 = deck1.clone();
        let mut deck2 = deck2.clone();
        let decks = (&mut deck1, &mut deck2);
        let cards = draw_pair(&decks);
        // actual game not yet implemented
    }
}

fn draw_pair(decks: &(&mut Deck, &mut Deck)) -> (Card, Card) {
    let (ref p1, ref p2) = *decks;

    (p1.draw_card(), p2.draw_card())
}

fn main() {
    play((Deck{}, Deck{}));
}
```

Comment: A `mut` reference is needed. It should be `let (ref mut p1, ref mut p2)`

Comment: @ElectricCoffee it is better to ask a new question instead of adding more problems to it, but I have included a possible solution to my answer. As I don't know your exact requirements, I am not sure it will work for you. Please consider to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem in the future.

Comment: I know, bad habit. But I figured I'd tack it on since it was related to the previous question. Someone asked how I used it, so that's why. Is there really no shorter way of doing that without modifying the type?